# Is possible to modify Request object?

Tags: laravel, request

Can somebody tell me if is possible to modify Request object in Laravel before it is used by aplication.
I need to remove specific url segment call App::setLocale() and then create Request instance.  It should be something like a middleware which has to be called between Aplication and Request. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "before it is used by aplication."

Comment: Before it is used for any other action.

Comment: By your application, or by the framework. "Any other action" is a bit vague, and one is considerably more difficult than the other.

Comment: I need to remove one specific segment from incomming url. Which contains locale information like en|fr|de but Request instance already contains the segments. I need to remove or modify it before it is used by router.

Comment: If you add your middleware to the kernel it should run before it touches your routes.

Comment: Yes but the route is based on the Request. I cant modify Request in the middleware. Is there something like Request->forget('url_segment'). This is waht I need to do.